# Disabling dynamic proxy creation for all entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm currently using Entity Framework 6 and dynamic proxies creation is enabled by default.

Is it a good idea to modify the context text template to include the following line?

```
this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

The generated context class constructor will end up like so:

```
public MyDbContext()
    : base("name=MyDbContext")
{
    this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with this.

Comment: Since this doesn't have any coding issues in terms of runtime or compiler error, this question is more suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com (a question and answer site for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development.).

Comment: It's neither a good idea or a bad idea.  You disable when you need to or want to, you leave it enabled if you don't care or want it.

Comment: It is never a good idea to mess with things you don't need or understand. Unless you do need to tweak it because something isn't working well.